# How do I close my AdSense account?

Tags: google-adsense

I need to close my AdSense account to change my status from individual to business.

As per [this AdSense help article](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9914?hl=en-GB), the instructions are:

> "In the “Account information” section, click cancel account."

However, there is no "Cancel account" button under *Account information*. So how can I close my account?

Answer (score 1):

You can, see screenshot below. Make sure you are the admin of that account.

[image: Screenshot of the Account Settings page]