# How to properly close Google AdSense account?

Tags: google-account, google-adsense

I had a Google AdSense account before (around 5 years ago) for an abandoned project. Now I have a new project and I want to monetize it with AdSense. I signed up for an account unknowingly I used the same email I used before. Fastforward I try to use the account but AdSense emails me and says:

> Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense. While reviewing your
>   application, we noticed that your account information matches a
>   currently approved AdSense account associated with email@example.com

When I try to sign in to the account `email@example.com` I see the following error messages:

> Fix these issues to connect to AdSense
>
> We see that you also have another AdSense account. We only allow one
>   account per person. To use this account, please close the other one.

How do I close the extra account? In the AdSense email the only account it mentions is the one connected with `email@example.com` but when I sign in to that account there is nothing there to close? I cannot access the settings or anything because the menu items are disabled/unclickable.

Here is a screenshot of the account

[image]

I have followed the [troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2594929) but my current problem is not covered there? I have also tried ticking the `I confirm I've closed the other account.` box and the steps that followed but the end result is still the same.

Hope anyone can help. Thanks

**UPDATE**

My question looks the same with this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56715/how-do-i-close-my-adsense-account), but it looks outdated and does not have the proper answers for my question.

Comment: I didn't find any obvious way to contact Google about a problem like this, but that's what I would recommend. In the absense of that possibility, have you checked the AdSense forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense ?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yes I have checked the adsense forum, posted my problem there too, but the forum doesn't look very helpful. My question didn't get a lot of attention there.

Comment: have anyone found any solution? I have same issue and cant close current account.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and have found the link to apply
for cancellation

https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/account_cancel
I have applied on 27.5.18 and waiting for a confirmatory mail about cancellation.

Comment: The link no longer works